# Int value of Prod in shapeless

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

Playing around with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) natural numbers in excitement, I wonder what could be the best approach to getting the integer value of e.g. a product of nats.

Excerpt from [shapeless `nat.scala`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/src/main/scala/shapeless/nat.scala):

```
trait Prod[A <: Nat, B <: Nat] {
  type Out <: Nat
}

trait ProdAux[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat]

object Prod {
  implicit def prod[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat](implicit diff : ProdAux[A, B, C]) = new Prod[A, B] {
    type Out = C
  }
}

object ProdAux {
  import Nat._0

  implicit def prod1[B <: Nat] = new ProdAux[_0, B, _0] {}
  implicit def prod2[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat, D <: Nat]
    (implicit ev1 : ProdAux[A, B, C], ev2 : SumAux[B, C, D]) = new ProdAux[Succ[A], B, D] {}
}
```

So far I've come up with the straightforward definition of

```
def toInt[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, C <: Nat](p: Prod[A, B])
    (implicit paux: ProdAux[A, B, C], iv: ToInt[C]): Int = iv()
```

As a matter of fact that approach would require somewhat redundant implementations of the equivalent code for e.g. sums, diffs, factorials etc. So I'd rather be able to use the "default" method `toInt[A <: Nat]`.

How would you do it? And is it possible to use the inner types (`Prod#Out`, `Sum#Out`, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I missed this question earlier (BTW, the [shapeless mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/shapeless-dev) is a good place to ask this kind of question).

I think you've slightly misunderstood the role of the `Prod` type class: its instances aren't themselves `Nat`s, they're witnesses of a relation holding between three `Nat`s, namely that `(A * B) == C`. As such, it doesn't really make all that much sense to convert `Prod` instances to `Int`s. Or rather, if it did, it'd make just as much sense for the resulting value to correspond to any of `A`, `B` or `C`, or the triple of all of them.

For use as proof terms in method definitions, the style you've shown is pretty much as intended ... see [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala#L67) for an example. Clearly though, this doesn't work very well for playing around with things on the REPL. To make that a bit smoother you could try things along the lines of,

```
def prod[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit prod : Prod[A, B]) =
  new { def toInt(implicit ti : ToInt[prod.Out]) = ti() }
```

which allows REPL interactions like,

```
scala> prod[_2, _3].toInt
res0: Int = 6
```

If this still isn't quite what you're after then please head over to the mailing list and sketch out what you'd like to be able to do.

Comment: Miles, thank you very much! In fact I did understand the `Prod` type class but I should have stated that in my OP more clearly. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for!